# How to get(Clipped)BoundingClientRect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a tooltip lib. It uses a styled `<div>`.
The red colored one. It was transformed 45 degree and clipped off.

[image]

I need a dynamic calculation of height for the clipped-red one above.
In this case the height is exactly `getBoundingClientRect().height / 2`,
the built in function is **transformed aware** but **not clipped aware**.
The **clip-path** property is might be customized, so we cannot just simply dividing the height by 2.

I need a custom js function something like: `getClippedBoundingClientRect()`